# iOs 9 uiWebView ignoring css inline

Tags: css, uiwebview, ios9, inline

I have an inline CSS being set by javascript on an element that is absolute positioned.

It's setting top: 88px.

uiWebView shows that this property is set to the element on styles panel but visually it never applies.

This element has several other CSS rules for the top attribute but all of them appears overridden.

If I comment them and let just one rule that applies the same top attribute style it works.

Any thoughts?

My HTML:

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader has-fixed-bottom scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header">
```

My CSS:

```
//overriden by inline CSS rule
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .has-header, .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-subheader {
    top: 44px;
}
//overriden by inline CSS rule
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .has-subheader {
    top: 108px;
}
//overriden by inline CSS rule
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-subheader, .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .has-header, .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .tabs-top>.tabs, .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .tabs.tabs-top {
    top: 64px;
}
// with this not commented works
.has-subheader {
    top: 88px;
}
.has-header {
    top: 44px;
}
```